# Next.js redux useSelector causes html mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm using **Next.js** to create a **React** app, and I'm using **redux** with **redux-toolkit** for state management.

I'm seeing an error in the console stating:
`Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <button> in <div>`.

I've seen this before, but I'm unsure why this is happening in this particular case.
Here is a simplified version of the component which has this issue:

```
const TopNav = (): JSX.Element => {
    const user = useSelector(selectAuthUser);

    return (
        <>
            <div>{!user && <LoginNavButton />}</div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Here is a workaround I've come up with, but I'm not sure why I have to do this:

```
const TopNav = (): JSX.Element => {
    const user = useSelector(selectAuthUser);
    const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!!user) setShowButton(true);
    }, [user]);

    return (
        <>
            <div>{showButton && <LoginNavButton />}</div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Can anyone explain why the basic usage of `useSelector()` and referring to state is causing this issue?  I'm assuming it's because the server doesn't have access to state, etc. however it seems like a pain to have to work around it like this for basic functionality.  Hence, I feel like I'm approaching it incorrectly :)

Answer (score 0):

just use 'use client' in order to use useSelecctor because useSelector run on client components .
in nextjs if you use a 'use client' on top of the page you wil be bale to use store data
like this below :

```
'use client'
const TopNav = (): JSX.Element => {
    const user = useSelector(selectAuthUser);

    return (
        <>
            <div>{!user && <LoginNavButton />}</div>
        </>
    );
};
```

in order to workaround for this problem you must use useSelector in another component which is not server component and pass the auth data with props to this component which will be like this

```
'use client'
const TopNav = (props): JSX.Element => {

return (
    <>
        <div>{!props.user && <LoginNavButton />}</div>
    </>
);
```

};